# vBulletin 4 - How do I branch a conditional based on usergroup?

Tags: syntax, conditional-statements, vbulletin, usergroups

I'm trying to replace a person's user name with their user title if they're a member of a certain user group. I've tried both

```
<vb:if condition="is_member_of($vbulletin->userinfo, 14)">
```

and

```
<vb:if condition="is_member_of($bbuserinfo, 14)">
```

and neither seem to be working.

This is what I have.

```
<a class="username {vb:raw memberinfo.online} popupctrl" href="{vb:link member, {vb:raw memberinfo}}" title="{vb:rawphrase {vb:raw memberinfo['onlinestatusphrase']}, {vb:raw memberinfo.username}}">
    <vb:if condition="is_member_of($vbulletin->userinfo, 14)">
    <!-- <vb:if condition="is_member_of($bbuserinfo, 14)"> -->
        <vb:if condition="$memberinfo['musername']">{vb:raw post.usertitle}
        <vb:else />{vb:raw post.usertitle}
        </vb:if>
    <vb:else /><strong>
        <vb:if condition="$memberinfo['musername']">{vb:raw memberinfo.musername}
        <vb:else />{vb:raw memberinfo.username}
        </vb:if></strong>
    </vb:if>
</a>
```

When I try to use this template, [this is what happens](https://gyazo.com/6831c75dfff23de388b04e2dd8e538cf) and [this is what it normally looks like](https://gyazo.com/ab82a761154e633da90b52d98715f461) with the code below.

The code I'm replacing is

```
<a class="username {vb:raw memberinfo.online} popupctrl" href="{vb:link member, {vb:raw memberinfo}}" title="{vb:rawphrase {vb:raw memberinfo['onlinestatusphrase']}, {vb:raw memberinfo.username}}">
<strong><vb:if condition="$memberinfo['musername']">{vb:raw memberinfo.musername}<vb:else />{vb:raw memberinfo.username}</vb:if></strong></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$vbulletin->userinfo` and `$bbuserinfo` grab the user *viewing the page*. What you want is to grab the user whose post you are iterating over. If you look at the context of your code, all of the vBulletin variables stem from `$memberinfo`. That's the current poster, and the variable we want.

Try:

```
<vb:if condition="is_member_of($memberinfo, 14)">
```

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense. I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: This worked! I tried to vote your solution up, but my score is too low for it to display right now.

Comment: You can still select it as the answer, however?

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested in vb4 template

```
<vb:if condition="$vbulletin->userinfo['usergroupid'] == 14">
User Belongs to the Group
<vb:else />
User Does not Belong to Group
</vb:if>
```

Thanks

Comment: I just tested that and it doesn't work. Every test results in "User does not belong to group".

Comment: If you look [here](http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/forum/general/php-html-questions/397022-little-help-with-if-condition?p=3419036#post3419036) you'll see the admin of vbulletin.com telling someone to use the format `<vb:if condition="is_member_of($bbuserinfo, 9)">` instead of your solution. The solution they have suggested is one which you can see I've included in my question.

Comment: Here is an example of both solutions side by side: [link to code in template](https://i.gyazo.com/2346a203ffae96edb345dcb069bc9d4b.png) and [the result](https://i.gyazo.com/6d9ea4f63e735fe9d0f42a5e2155dd7c.png). Can you give me examples and output pictures of it working on your forum, please?